# How do I identify where the last record added is greater than 34 days old

Tags: sql-server

I have an invoicing processing application.  The goal is to identify accounts that ***have not had an invoiced processed*** in 35 days.  So, if an invoice has not be received and or has not been processed, I need a report that will show the Account the invoice is associated with.

Comment: And google SQL Server date functions.

Comment: Here is the query I use to get data for invoices with invoice date between -35 day and today.  What I need to identify is where an invoice does not exist.  Another words, an account does not have an invoice record recorded in 35 days.

Select distinct * from Invoices i
join InvoiceAccountReferences ia on ia.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId
where i.InvoiceDate between DATEADD(day, -35, GETDATE()) and GetDate()

Comment: [edit] any additional information into your question please.

Comment: Tip: try `not exists`

Comment: I need to be able to query my database and identify if the last invoice date provided is 35 days old and another invoice for the account has not been recored.

Comment: [tips-for-asking-a-good-sql-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Using not exist has some sence in it, but I need to identify if an invoice record has not been added for an account within a 35 day period.

Comment: Ok.  I am not trying to argue whether I asked a good question or not but I believe my question is pretty straight forward.  I have provided the query used to get invoices within a 35 day period.  Please help me understand what my question is not providing you to understand what I am asking for.  I need to identify whether I have a record in the invoices table for an account every 35 days.  Another words I need to be able to identify if I have not submitted an invoice record in 35 days.  If I have not then an invoice has been missed.  I need to follow and get one.

Comment: Sorry my thinking was off.  I need to identify accounts that have not had an invoice provided for it.  So the logic is give me all account where an invoice does not exist over a 35 day period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured it out.  Thank you all for your contributions.

```
WITH ACCOUNT_PROCESSEDDATE AS (
SELECT S.AccountId, S.AccountNumber, MAX(I.ProcessedDate) AS MAXProcessDate FROM 
ServiceAccounts S
JOIN InvoiceAccountReferences IAR ON IAR.AccountId = S.AccountId
JOIN Invoices I ON I.InvoiceId = IAR.InvoiceId
WHERE YEAR(I.InvoiceDate) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY S.AccountId, S.AccountNumber)

SELECT AccountNumber, MAXProcessDate FROM ACCOUNT_PROCESSEDDATE WHERE MAXProcessDate 
NOT BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -35, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```